# What's the order of the alignment zones in BlueValues of PostScript Type 1 Font?

Tags: fonts, postscript

I have read the Type 1 Font Spec. but didn't manage to find any materials on the order of the alignment zones in BluesValues.

Could you help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only requirement for the BlueValues is that element 0 represents the Base-Line Overshoot. The interpretation of the other values is up to the whim of the font creator.

Check section 5.3, page 36 for all the rules. <strike>It's bascially a data cache for the encoded charstrings (which describe the font shapes themselves) so the strings can save space. So the first element is the bottom; the last one is the top; and the middle ones define an ascending "scale" for the uniform vertical positions in the font.</strike>
 [I was wrong. That's not what they're for.]

The values must be in strict ascending order. Each pair declares the bottom and top (ascending, remember) of an alignment zone; the "outer" value representing the extent of rounded parts of glyphs, the "inner" value representing the extent of the flat parts of glyphs, both parts refering to the same "logical" height.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the pairs need be in any order, though I believe they usually are, since they only define alignment zones and they certainly don't describe uniform vertical positions.

The first pair is defined as the baseline and the baseline overshoot. This is important because, unlike the other BluesValues, this is a *bottom* zone. The remaining pairs describe top zones. page 37 of the type 1 specification gives some examples of the glyph features which might be hinted using top zones.

Comment: 5.2: "Many of these hints declare constraints on the vertical positions of character features across the entire font."

Comment: To be honest, too busy.... Answering questions (especially Ghostscript questions) is the only reason I spend time here. Part of maintaining our profile.

Comment: Understood. That's more than enough I suppose. Your post are often invaluable.